# Excel 2013 Print to PDF in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

As it seems that Excel 2013 allow for direct Save as to PDF format, how can in perform this using VBA code ? I would like to build a macro that will automatically create a PDF from a worksheet (with the name of the file being passed as String variable).
Many thanks to you all

Comment: Try the macro recorder perhaps?  It might show you.

Comment: [This link](http://www.excelguru.ca/content.php?161-Printing-Worksheets-To-A-PDF-File-(Using-Early-Binding) shows example code to do this.   And welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: Joe, you're totally right. Though it seemed obvious, it skipped my mind. Found out that Excel 2013 treats this as  ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
Dim fp As String
Dim wb As Workbook

fp = "C:\temp\foo.pdf"
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

wb.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
                       Filename:=fp, _
                       Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
                       IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
                       IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
                       OpenAfterPublish:=False
```

*Note that `ExportAFixedFormat`must have all its variables on one line or it will not compile.

**Note that the '_' characters should allow this to compile whilst not being all on one line

Comment: I started getting a 1004 error from this and found that fully specifying the path is now crucial, and `ActiveWorkbook.Path` can help in that