# How to Print to PDF?

Tags: excel, vba

I tried the following solution to print from Excel to PDF:

[Excel 2013 Print to PDF in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15030180/excel-2013-print-to-pdf-in-vba)

It produces

> run time error 1004

on `wb.ExportAsFixedFormat`.

My version of Excel: 2007.

I changed the file path so it would save to my desktop.

```vb
Sub Invoice_to_PFD()
    'Saves the invoice print area to a PDF file
    
    Dim fp As String
    Dim wb As Workbook
    
    fp = "C:\desktop\NewInvoice.pdf"
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    
    wb.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=fp, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True
    
End Sub
```

Comment: works fine for me in both 2007 & 2010... your error is in which line exactly?

Comment: It is in the line [code]wb.ExportAsFixedFormat[/code] - does it work if you change the file path as well? Already thought that maybe the path could be invalid?

Comment: yes, exactly, that's possible and this will be the reason...!

Comment: Alright I see. So if I simply want to save it to the Desktop and call the file "NewInvoice.pdf", how do I reference the path correctly? And is there a way to create an input for the path as I am planning to give this to someone else and I think he uses Mac OS and therefore might need completely different fp references to make it work? Thanks!

Comment: I don't know how to set universal path for both Win and Mac. For Win you could try something like: `fp = environ("userprofile") & "\desktop\NewInvoice.pdf"`

Comment: Definitely file access rights or folder/path issues. Do you have that "desktop" folder? Did you try with different path? e.g. c root only? Also try with "\\" instead of "\"

Comment: Thank you for all your comments; it turned out to be a path issue - I changed the path to "C:\Users\Matthias\Desktop\NewInvoice.pdf" and it works just fine! Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is the working code now for Windows users (Mac OS might have to adjust file path):

```
Sub Invoice_to_PDF()
'Saves the invoice print area to a PDF file

Dim fp As String
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet

fp = "C:\Users\[username]\Desktop\NewInvoice.pdf"
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set ws = Worksheets("Invoice")

ws.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=fp, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If the worksheet that you are exporting contains no data then the export fails. I found this solution on the MrExcel forum, where someone appears to have stumbled over the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Another cause of this error is if the filename contains illegal characters such as:

- < (less than)
- > (greater than)
- : (colon)
- " (double quote)
- / (forward slash)
- \ (backslash)
- | (vertical bar or pipe)
- ? (question mark)
- * (asterisk)

See 'Naming conventions' here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/fileio/naming-a-file

**Solution:** replace illegal characters with legal ones, such as '_'.

Answer (score 0):

I had to remove line breaks in my filename's variable using the clean function:

xlName = Range("CustomerName").Value
xlName = Application.WorksheetFunction.Clean(xlName)

Answer (score -1):

OK, I just played with mine some more, and if I take the ".pdf" off the filename specification, I don't get the error 1004.