# Excel print to PDF - not working without error code returned

Tags: pdf, excel, vba

I have encountered a very strange problem with a previously working piece of code that was discussed [here a while ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17379700/excel-vba-to-print-to-pdf-run-time-error-1004/17384194#17384194).

This code used to do exactly what it should: save the part of the sheet inside the print area as a PDF file. However, after changing the code in another module of the same Excel file, this code does not execute anymore, without returning any error message at all.

It would be great if someone could test that code on their machine and tell me whether or not it works or at least returns any error at all? Code is below; I can provide more code from other modules in the file as well as screenshots, if necessary. Many thanks for your help!

```
Sub Invoice_to_PDF()
'Saves the invoice print area to a PDF file

Dim fp As String
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet

fp = "C:\Users\Matthias\Desktop\NewInvoice.pdf"
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set ws = Worksheets("Invoice")

ws.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=fp, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Code works great, no error is returned. Tested on Excel 2010 with a fresh file containing only this method and few data.

Comment: Have you tried applying less or different attributes to the ExportAsFixedFormat method? 

Is it working if you manually set the PrintArea right before executing this particular function on its own?

Have you installed/uninstalled PDF add-ins recently?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have played with some attributes, manually set the print area - no change. I have not installed or uninstalled any PDF add-ins either. It simply does nothing when I execute the code now. Strange: on a friend's machine it apparently prduced a run time error 1001(?), so it might have to do with the version of Excel (mine is Mac 2011), or maybe the printer settings...?

Comment: Have you tried placing a breakpoint at the beginning of the function and then go through it step-by-step (F8)? To do so, click in the margin of the line at which you want the execution to pause (or click on the line and press F9). At which line does the execution stops?