# Printout Method produces corrupted pdf file

Tags: vba, excel

When I execute the following codes, the resulting abc.pdf file seems to be corrupted. Does anyone know why, and what is the solution? However if I take out prtofilename my code seems to be working fine. Thanks in advance.

```
Sub printpdf()
  Selection.PrintOut ActivePrinter:="adobe PDF", prtofilename:="ABC.pdf"
End Sub
```

Comment: You are essentially saving or exporting as PDF, this has been discussed already here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15030180/excel-2013-print-to-pdf-in-vba