# Using excel .PrintOut is creating corrupt .pdf files

Tags: excel, vba, pdf

I am using the following code to create a .pdf document based in an excel object:

```
filenameWithPath = "C:\" & xlApp.Workbooks(1).Name & ".pdf"
Call xlApp.Workbooks(1).PrintOut(, , , , , , , filenameWithPath)
```

In my machine it works fine, I can open the .pdf file created. But when I do this process in other computer the .pdf created don't open and says it is an invalid .pdf file format.

Due to guarantee compatibility with excel 2003 I can't use the "ExportAsFixedFormat" provided in excel versions >= 2007.

I can't do it with PDF Distiller too.

Anybody had this issue before?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This might [help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15030180/excel-2013-print-to-pdf-in-vba)

Comment: This is not a VB6 question at all.  Not even a programming question, but a question about versions of MS Office.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @DaBeau96 I came to an answer for my problem.

I used the method

```
xlApp.Workbooks(1).ExportAsFixedFormat(0, filenameWithPath)
```

like this and now I don't have problems in compiling the exe.

Thanks for all the comments.